# Error while fetching image from firebase storage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am creating blog app and during fetching image from firebase storage it throws error.
I have written the following code:

```
  body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
      query: dbRef.child('Post List'),
      itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
        return Container(
          child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              placeholder: 'assets/icon.png',
              image: "snapshot.value['pImage']"),
        );
      },
    )
```

It throws following error:

```
  assert(() {
              if (widget.errorBuilder == null) {
                // ignore: only_throw_errors, since we're just proxying the error.
                throw error; // Ensures the error message is printed to the console.
              }
              return true;
```

Images of debug console output is as following:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image: "snapshot.value['pImage']"),
```

I think that is the cause of error. Remove "" from here. Or:

```
image: "${snapshot.value['pImage']}"),
```

Comment: No that's not the problem. Even if I set the url of asset image it shows the same error.

Comment: are you sure? Restart app after doing my changes. "snapshot.value['pImage']" you know this is read as simple string not as url. "${snapshot.value['pImage']}" is read as url. So just do as I said and attentively check. What is an error. Your screenshots are just debug messages. Show the error lines!

Comment: are you sure? Restart app after doing my changes. "snapshot.value['pImage']" you know this is read as simple string not as url. "${snapshot.value['pImage']}" is read as url. So just do as I said and attentively check. What is an error. Your screenshots are just debug messages. Show the error lines!

Comment: And learn to accept correct answers and upvote. I saw your account. It is impossible to not find correct answer for so many questions.

Comment: I tried your answer and now it shows that the value can be null.

Comment: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251701/discussion-between-jakhongir-anasov-and-suresh-yadav).

Comment: I added the null check but it's not solved the problem.

Comment: So the solution is "$(snapshot.value as dynamic)['pImage']"